# How to create class that will only receive dependency in classpath at runtime?

Tags: java, maven

I work for a company that distributes our product as a jar file, and I'm trying to write something that will be able to test past versions of these jars with various inputs. Ideally, I could then run the test framework like

```
java -jar testframework.jar -cp "version1.jar"
```

or

```
java -jar testframework.jar -cp "version2.jar"
```

and get different outputs. Since the methods that take in input are set in stone, I figured I could make the dependency on our product scope "provided" or "runtime" in maven, and then call input methods on whatever version of the jar was provided in the classpath. Something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ourCompany</groupid>
  <artifactId>ourProduct</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and then in the main TestFramework class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ProductClass.doSomething();
}
```

However, I'm getting a compilation error that the doSomething method doesn't exist. I imagine I'm misunderstanding exactly what "provided" and "runtime" mean with respect to maven dependencies, but I haven't been able to find any resources that explain my mistake. Does anyone know how I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you getting compilation error when you specify the `scope` as `provided` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting "cannot find symbol. symbol: doSomething()"

Comment: Is `ProductJar` you mean a class inside `ProductJar` ? It is misleading...

Comment: Good point. Yes, I meant a class within ProductJar. I edited for clarity.

Comment: I doubt that `ProductClass` does not exist inside the jar, so is the error when you say `provided` scope

Comment: Yes, `ProductClass` definitely exists within `ProductJar`. It has no problem importing the class, just calling the method `doSomething`. And I'm getting that error when I use `provided` scope.

Comment: Do you call doSomething exactly like in this example? Have you then made sure that it's actually a static method and not an instance method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ProductClass` definitely exists within `ProductJar`. It has no
>   problem importing the class, just calling the method `doSomething`. And
>   I'm getting that error when I use `provided` scope.

Because you are confirming that the JAR exists, the issue seems like with the version of the JAR file you are pointing to, so specify the **`<version>X</version>`** (in which the `doSomething` method exist) as well for the `<dependency>` and should solve the problem.

> I'm misunderstanding exactly what "provided" and "runtime" mean with
>   respect to maven dependencies

`provided` and `runtime` scopes are completely different, they are for two different purposes.

**`provided` scope means that the dependency is required during compile** and test time (but, the dependency JAR will not be bundled as part of the JAR packaging, so the JAR should be available in the container classpath)

**`runtime` scope means that the dependency is required only during execution** of the program, not at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies always need to be available at compile time.  Otherwise, how would the compiler be able to know if your code is valid or not?  Check that the version you've declared in the dependency does indeed have the `doSomething` method you want to use.  If not you will need to change the version to one that does have that method.